# How to extract background image and text from a image

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, python-tesseract

I have an image and am trying to separate the background image and text. 
For text I have used pytesseract and it gives me all the data. Now my aim is to translate this text and place it back on the image. 
For that I need the background image and the position of the text where I need to put the text back.

I need some help or pointers as I have been trying to use OpenCV for same but no luck yet.

Thanks 
-Megha

Comment: Did you try some codes or some examples in opencv

Comment: I am trying sample in OpenCV. Reference :: https://likegeeks.com/python-image-processing/#Extracting-text-from-Image-OCR

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592055/opencv-remove-text-from-image you should have a look here