# remove red text from image

Tags: python, opencv

How can I remove the red text from image,[image]

```
src = cv2.imread('original.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
src[:,:,2] = np.zeros([src.shape[0], src.shape[1]])
#cv2.imwrite('changed.png',src)
```

this does remove the red color but also gives it a blueish background,how can I fix this or maybe do it in a better way.

Ideally the output would be like this

[image: output]

Comment: you are removing the red channel from image not the red "color"

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592055/opencv-remove-text-from-image

Comment: Threshold on red to make a mask. Then use cv2.inpaint()

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your extracting the image's Red Component, and not the image's red channel itself. Try the following:

```
src = cv2.imread('original.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(src.shape)

#extract red channel
red_channel = src[:,:,2]

#write red channel to greyscale image
cv2.imwrite('changed.png', red_channel)
```

Below you'll see resources that describe the difference. If you found this useful please mark as answer. Thanks

Resources:

- Extract Red Component: https://pythonexamples.org/python-opencv-remove-red-channel-from-color-image/
- Extract Red Channel: https://pythonexamples.org/python-opencv-extract-red-channel-of-image/

Comment: What changes should be made in the code if I want to keep only a particular color? Inmy case, I want to keep black color text only.