# Remove letter artifacts from mammography image

Tags: python, opencv, artifacts

I want to remove the letter artifacts "L:CC and Strin" from breast mammography using `python`. How could I get that done? this is my image

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Could you add some of your code?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592055/opencv-remove-text-from-image)

Comment: If the letters are perfectly white (255,255,255) and no other pixels are perfectly white in the image, then just change white to black by thresholding to find the white pixels and use that as a mask. `image[mask=255] = (0,0,0)`

Comment: letters are also of different intensity. not perfectly white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Threshold
- Dilate as mask
- Apply mask to change white letters to black
- Save the results

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('mammogram_letters.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create mask
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 247, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# dilate mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# apply change
result = img.copy()
result[mask == 255] = (0,0,0)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("mammogram_letters_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("mammogram_letters_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("mammogram_letters_blackened.png", result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Mask image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to get pixel coordinate of the box containing test, if they are always the same my code will work.

```
    from PIL import Image
    im = Image.open('SqbIx.png')
    img =im.load()
    for i in range (73,116):
            for j in range (36,57):
                img[i,j]= (0, 0, 0)
    im.save('mod.png')
```

Comment: thanks for help. artifacts are at different positions in all images