# How to remove text from an x-ray image using python

Tags: python, image, image-preprocessing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Fyf.jpg)

How can I remove the text from the image?

Comment: You can find the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592055/opencv-remove-text-from-image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV - Remove text from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592055/opencv-remove-text-from-image)